# Perform a function only after the first function is completed - ios

Tags: ios, objective-c, performselector, localnotification

In my app, I push local notifications after the user does a certain action.
When the user opens the app from the pushed notification, I want to register an event to a tracking system (in my case is **Mixpanel**).
I should have a key to register the event which I'm getting this from my server.

So what I want to do is to get the key in a function and after this function has finished, I want to register the event.

I tried `performSelectorOnMainThread:withObject:waitUntilDone:` but it didn't work

```
- (BOOL)application:(UIApplication *)application didFinishLaunchingWithOptions:(NSDictionary *)launchOptions
{
    //some code here
    [self performSelectorOnMainThread:@selector(performHandShake)
                           withObject:nil
                        waitUntilDone:YES];
    [self performSelectorOnMainThread:@selector(registerLaunchOptionsDetails:) 
                           withObject:launchOptions
                        waitUntilDone:YES];
    //some code here
}

-(void)performHandShake
{
   //myParams here

    [[RKClient sharedClient] get:@"/handshake" usingBlock:^(RKRequest *request) {
        request.params = [RKParams paramsWithDictionary:myParams];
        request.method = RKRequestMethodGET;

        request.onDidLoadResponse = ^(RKResponse *response) {
            //Set the tracking key here 
        };

        request.onDidFailLoadWithError = ^(NSError *error) {
            NSLog(@"ERROR:%@",error);
        };
    }];
}

-(void)registerLaunchOptionsDetails:(NSDictionary *)launchOptions
{
    UILocalNotification *localNotification = [launchOptions objectForKey: UIApplicationLaunchOptionsLocalNotificationKey];

    if (localNotification) {
       //Register the event here using the key 
    }
 }
```

The problem is the `registerLaunchOptionsDetails` function performed before `performHandShake` is completed and the events are not being registered.

Comment: Can you just call the `registerLaunchOptionsDetails` function at the end of the handshake function?

Comment: You Have just to use Grand Central Dispatch in this case. Using Queues  is recommended in these situations

Comment: try to call callregisterLaunchOptionsDetails from onDidLoadResponse block?

Comment: @Ali I tried it but it didn't work for me and I think the reason is because I didn't fully understand it. Any recommended links with good example?

Comment: @alex thank you, it works. You can add your comment as answer and I'll accept it.

Comment: nevermind, upvotes aren't my goal over here:) I'm glad to help u.

Answer (score 1):

It might be overkill for what you want to do but there is a library similar to async for node. You can chain async tasks together and/or wait till multiple are done before performing another action.

[ReactiveCocoa](https://github.com/ReactiveCocoa/ReactiveCocoa)

Answer (score 1):

When you execute `-[RKClient get:usingBlock]`, it will create a network operation that will be executed in the background and the method will return.

This will clear the path to `registerLaunchOptionsDetails` run, which will happen before the network operation has completed.

The `request.onDidLoad` will run when the network operation is completed successfully and you have the data that was requested. Which is why calling `registerLaunchOptionsDetails:` there will work there.

Comment: Thank you for the explanation of [RKClient get:usingBlock]. I didn't know that. This helps me in understanding the things.

Answer (score 1):

Block `request.onDidLoadResponse` will be invoked when you need, so you need to call `registerLaunchOptionsDetails:` from this block. Don't forget to pass `launchOptions` to this block through `performHandShake` and create weak reference to `self` to prevent it from retain in block.
Final code should be like this:

```
- (BOOL)application:(UIApplication *)application didFinishLaunchingWithOptions:(NSDictionary *)launchOptions
{
    //some code here

    [self performSelectorOnMainThread:@selector(performHandShake:) withObject:launchOptions waitUntilDone:YES];


    //some code here

}

-(void)performHandShake:(NSDictionary *)launchOptions
{
    //myParams here

        [[RKClient sharedClient] get:@"/handshake" usingBlock:^(RKRequest *request){

        request.params = [RKParams paramsWithDictionary:myParams];
        request.method = RKRequestMethodGET;

        __weak AppDelegate *weakSelf = self;
        request.onDidLoadResponse = ^(RKResponse *response)
        {

            //Set the tracking key here

            // Here is registerLaunchOptionsDetails: call
            [weakSelf registerLaunchOptionsDetails:launchOptions];
        };

        request.onDidFailLoadWithError = ^(NSError *error)
        {
            NSLog(@"ERROR:%@",error);
        };
    }];

}

-(void)registerLaunchOptionsDetails:(NSDictionary *)launchOptions
{

    UILocalNotification *localNotification = [launchOptions objectForKey: UIApplicationLaunchOptionsLocalNotificationKey];

    if (localNotification)
    {
        //Register the event here using the key 


    }
}
```